# Signalr Delay Receive broadcast to all connected clients

Tags: c#, signalr

When I Broadcast a message by below code:

```
Clients.All.getRecentitem(ProductId, UserName, Price, timespan, Date);
```

It will be received by all connected clients. I am sending a `timespan` from above code and at client side a timer is set from `timespan`.

When I broadcast all clients do not receive the notification at the same time. Some clients receive with a delay of 1-2 seconds. So my timer is set with a delay of 1-2 seconds.

Suggest any solution using which all connected clients can receive broadcast messages at the sametime.

> I am using signalR-1.1.4.

Comment: Which protocols are beeing used by the clients that recieve the data with a delay? Maybe they use long polling in stead of websockets

Comment: I have not specify any protocol. But i think it use websockets. I have created this app from demo chat app of signalr.

Comment: when i try Context.QueryString["transport"] it shows serverSentEvents.